# Is there a configuration option in azds.yaml to increase the timeout during azds up?

Tags: azure-aks

The "azds up" command times out before all the steps are done. I have a large Angular app that typically takes 5 minutes+ when npm install is executed. When I execute azds up this is what I get:

```
Step 1/9 : FROM node
Step 2/9 : ENV PORT 80
Step 3/9 : WORKDIR /app
Step 4/9 : COPY package*.json ./
Step 5/9 : RUN npm install --silent
Waiting for container...
```

and then it returns to the command line.

Is there a configuration in the azds.yaml where I can tell azds/helm to wait for a longer period of time?

Thanks!

Comment: If you use the `azds up --verbose` switch do you get any more details on what's happening?

Also if you run `kubectl get pods` or look in the kubernetes dashboard do you see your pod and is there any additional information available there?

Answer (score 0):

To begin with i will give some examples that  might be  helpful in your case:

1. **An example of .yaml of how to rolling upgrade**

```
spec:
  minReadySeconds: 60
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 50%
      maxUnavailable: 50%
```

> - **minReadySeconds**: The bootup time of your application, Kubernetes    waits specific time until the next pod creation. For
>     example    minReadySeconds is 60 then after the Pod become healthy the
>     Deployment must wait for 60 seconds to update the next Pod.
> - **progressDeadlineSeconds** Timeout value for updating one pod in this    example 10 minutes. If the rollout fails to progress in 10
>     minutes,    then the Deployment is marked as failed and finished, also
>     all of    next job never invoke.
> - **maxSurge**: The maxSurge parameter controls how many extra resources    can be created during the rollout.(Absolute value or %)
> - **maxUnavailable**: The maxUnavailable parameter sets the maximum number    of Pods that can be unavailable during a rolling
>     update.(Absolute    value or %)

2. **An example of .yaml Liveness & Readiness**

```
livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 3
```

The above manifest configured livenessProbes which confirm whether an container is running properly or not.

It probe the health check by using HTTP GET request to /healthz with port 8080.

> The probe sets an **initialDelaySeconds**=60 which means that it will not
>   be called until 60 seconds after all the containers in the Pod are
>   created. And **timeoutSeconds**=1 was configured it means that the probe
>   must respond with in the 1 second timeout. The **periodSeconds**=10 was
>   configured, it means that the probe invoke every 10 seconds. If more
>   than 3 probe failed(failureThreshold=3), the container will be
>   considerd un-healthy and failed and restart.

```
  readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 120
          timeoutSeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 3
```

> The above readinessProbe is more important than liveness probe in
>   production environment. the readinessProbe is confirm whether the
>   service can acceptable or not. If this probe failed, the internal
>   loadbalancer never send the traffic to this pod. Only successed the
>   probe, the traffic to this pod will start.